# Are we more like the world building Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion

For this question [What are good specifications for naming packages/modules in a language?](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/q/335/285)
I commented:

> On regular stack overflow this would risk being closed as opinion based and/or too broad. You might want to try and constrain the question more.

A refreshing reply to my comment was:

> This isn’t Stack Overflow, we are more like Worldbuilding or UX in that respect (in fact, we are UX for the people who build UX :P)

But that question ended up being closed as did a much better worded question: [How can isolated focus on syntax be counterproductive in the earlier stages of a language's design?](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/888/how-can-isolated-focus-on-syntax-be-counterproductive-in-the-earlier-stages-of-a)

By "like world building" I think we mean:

- We accept questions which have no single correct answer
- We allow multiple answers to questions which support different views

So are we more like [world building](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/) or not?

Comment: as someone who knows nothing about worldbuilding.se and has basically never visited it expect to flag spam from smokey, the way this question is framed is not particularly _accessible_. But that's just me. Maybe a lot of people here will get it. If not, a different framing (or at least a more accessible title) may be worthwhile.

Comment: The second question ended up getting reopened

Comment: @starball Ironically I don't know what you mean by spam from smokey. But point taken my explanation is in my answer which might end up being voted down instead of something else.

Comment: @seggan my work here is done :)

Answer (score 9):

By "like world building" we mean:

- We accept questions which have no single correct answer
- We allow multiple answers to questions which support different views

I think this is true already and it is a good thing.
Stack overflow closes these sorts of questions. World building does not.
Building a programming language is somewhat like building a world.

Some example of such questions were shared here - https://languagedesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/147/285

Comment: SO absolutely does accept questions which has no single correct answer. That's why the software allows multiple answers. If by “we accept questions which have no single correct answer” you mean that answers should be rated purely subjectively, you're trying to reinvent Programmers Stack Exchange, and [that didn't go well the first time around](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22programmers%22). (I'm sure there's a good link somewhere that explains the story, but frankly I can't be bothered finding it.)

Comment: Yes, multiple answers are allowed on SO but questions tend to be closed if they are a matter of opinion. Here you might ask a question where answers from several points of view are valuable. https://languagedesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69/what-are-pros-and-cons-of-pros-cons/70#70

Answer (score 3):

World building is about fiction, not constrained by reality if it gets in the way of a good story. Programming language design is very much constrained by mathematics, physics and engineering, as well as the neurological and sociological environment of programming. Being more like Worldbuilding.SE would not be a good thing.

Comment: Arguably, PLDI is more like [conlang.SE] than World Building. Programming language design is constrained, but like UX, it's also inherently about tradeoffs.

Answer (score 2):

### Yes, we are like User Experience, Constructed Languages, Code Review, and many others where there are many valid answers to a given question

The entire reason we wanted to split off from computer science is so we could ask a bit more opinionated but still highly relevant questions where there is no one correct view.

This format has proven many times to work well in the stack exchange format.

Answer (score -1):

In some ways, absouletly. For example, question get a ton of answers and most questions here are subjective and open to many answers. And I don't think that there anything wrong with that. Although if you look at the reasons in Gilles answer, we shouldn't be exactly like worldbuilding. But certain aspects are fine. As to your 2 original criteria, we are definetly like worldbuilding.